# What safety precautions should I take when hiking in an area with bears?

Tags: bears, appalachian-trail

I am planning a hike on the Appalachian Trail. I have never hiked in an area with bears. What safety precautions should I take to avoid them (or for them to avoid me) and what should I do if I encounter a bear?

Is it safe for someone with no experience with bears to hike on the Appalachian Trail where there are bears?

Comment: Welcome Julia. We already have a lots of questions discussing about precautions need to be taken while camping in areas with Bears. I will request you to please go through them first, and if it doesn't clear your doubts, then your always welcome to come up with a specific question.

Comment: For example: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/225/2303

Comment: @WedaPashi I see. Sorry about that!

Comment: Not a problem. Hope it answered your questions.